# Implementing stateless NPC scripting with coroutines/C# 5's await

Tags: c#, scripting, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm trying to implement NPC scripting using C#'s new `await` feature. [This is my proof of concept.](https://github.com/angelsl/csharpmisc)

In [`NPC.cs`](https://github.com/angelsl/csharpmisc/blob/master/NPC.cs#L18) you can see this snippet:

```
public async void Run(INPC npc)
{
    npc.Say("Hello!");
    await npc.WaitForOk();
    npc.Say("This is an example of some weird crap.");
    await npc.WaitForOk();
    npc.Say("Bye.");
    await npc.WaitForOk();
}
```

In a real example the script would be implemented in a scripting language like IronPython. Even though it may support the `async`/`await` keywords in the future, having to do that for every call is very troublesome and annoying.

I've tried having another method be async and do the await, and having the script simply call that, but due to the way `async`/`await` works, the script method (`Run`) would simply continue without pausing/blocking.

Is there a way to avoid having to make the script method async and having to use `await` in front of each call, while still retaining coroutine-like functionality?

Also, if there is a better solution to this already available than to use `async`/`await` while still being thread-efficient, please highlight it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's a very interesting use for `async`/`await`.

I've compiled a lot of syntax-related questions from around the web into [one of my blog posts](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html). In short, there are good reasons why `async` and `await` are both required.

If you're willing to add state to your NPCs, consider using an observer-based approach ([Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609)). This approach is capable of complex interactions, and could also allow parallel execution of different NPCs.

You could also pattern your NPCs on threadpool tasks, which are pretty efficient - when they block, the CPU is made available for other tasks.

Comment: I've actually thought of using the ThreadPool with AutoResetEvents; whenever `NPC.WaitForOk()` is called, it would send the request to the client, then `WaitOne()`.

I've never seen ThreadPool threads with that behaviour.. [the MSDN documentation even states the opposite.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx)

Comment: You're correct - the threadpool threads will block. I meant to say the CPU is made available.

Comment: Ah.. that makes more sense. But in a real application, there might be hundreds or thousands of NPC conversations happening simultaneously; having that many blocked threads at once just feels .. 'hacky'. I'll check out the Rx though, but I'll wait for other answers before picking my accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @angelsl, it's not only hacky, it's also a very bad idea. Each thread consumes 1 MB of memory (by default). And so having a thousand NPCs, each with their own thread, means consuming 1 GB of memory unnecessarily. THreadPool really wasn't meant for things like this.

Comment: @svick: That's what I thought too. Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why are you trying to avoid `await` so hard. I think it's a good idea to require it for this kind of code, because it would be hard to tell what the code actually does otherwise. So, my opinion is that using `await` this way is probably your best option.

Also, it's a good idea to avoid `async void` methods, if you can, since you can't catch exceptions they throw.

I can imagine there are ways to avoid writing `async`, like:

```
npc.AddAction(n => n.Say("Hello!"))
   .AddAction(n => n.WaitForOk())
   .AddAction(n => n.Say("This is an example of some weird crap."))
   .AddAction(n => n.WaitForOk());

npc.Run();
```

Here, `Run()` processes the list of actions built using `AddAction()` and uses `await` where necessary.

But I doubt you can make it as simple as your code with `await`s. (Also, implementing any kind of control flow in a code like this would make it really unreadable.)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using `await` everywhere because in a real gameserver, scripts would be implemented via something like IronPython or IronRuby, and it may or may not support `await`/`async`. Plus the `WaitFor`blah methods would be used in context and it'd be known that they would 'suspend' the script execution. So that is why I'm trying to avoid having `await` everywhere.

Comment: If it was that simple, then `await` wouldn't really be necessary, would it? What `await` does it that it completely rewrites the code of the method. And you're basically asking how to do that in a language that doesn't support it. Well, without using some bad hacks, you can't.